# Jquery fancybox won't open div

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to get a form to pop up when the Auto Loan Calculator link at the bottom of  [this](http://dev.mww.venus.stellarbluewebdesign.com/carsales/single_vehicle/53) page is clicked.

The function call I am making looks like this

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#auto-calc-link').click(function(){
        $.fancybox.open($('#auto-loan-container'));
    });
});
```

The head section is a bit of a mess at the moment, but the files for the fancybox are definitely linked... Console isn't spitting anything out so I don't know where to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            type: "iframe",
            helpers   : { 
      overlay : {
      closeClick: false}
      // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox
      },
      closeClick  : false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox
      scrolling     : 'no',
      width         : 550,
      height        : 0,
      autoScale     : true,
      openEffect    : 'elastic',
      closeEffect   : 'fade',
      closeBtn : true,

        }).trigger("onclick");

    });
```

And you should have this link below.

```
<a class="fancybox" href="example.com"></a>
```

Comment: Tried it.. still didn't work. I'm not getting anything like fancybox is not a function which I think is wierd